# Why is my Solidity for loop if statement code is not giving the right result?

Tags: solidity

The if statement in my for loop code is not filtering as intended, I want to believe I am missing something here but I can not seem to figure it out.

Here is the code, I hid the unnecessary code:

```
contract SolahParchiThap {
address owner = msg.sender;
address[4] p;
uint8[4][4] aparchis;
uint endgame;
uint newgame;
uint startTime;
uint8 turn;
uint id;
uint8 value;

modifier onlyOwner {require(msg.sender == owner); _;}

mapping (address => uint8[4]) _players;
mapping(uint => mapping(address => bool)) allPlayers;
mapping(address => uint) users;
mapping(address => uint256) wins;
```

---

The issue is with the code below, the `claimWin` function. A win is only valid when a player in the game has at least one of the numbers in his/her `array[]` equal to 4. For example, `_players` contains a mapping of the four players to the following numbers for each person.

`[["4","0","0","0"],["0","2","1","1"],["0","1","2","1"],["0","1","1","2"]]`

for every player of the game,

clearly, the current winner is player 1, i.e array[0] because he has on number that is 4.

when I call the below function player two is able to claim a win, and sometimes the code goes straight to the revert() code line.

```
// To claim win
function claimWin() public {
    uint v = checkP();
    require (v != 7, "You are not a valid member of this game");

    uint8[4] memory dt =_players[msg.sender];

    for (uint8 e; e < 4; e++){
        if(dt[e] == 4){
            wins[msg.sender] += 1;
        } else {
            revert();
        }
    } 
}


//To end the game
function endGame() public {
    newgame = 0;
    p[0] = p[1] = p[2] = p[3] = address(0);
}

function checkP() view internal returns (uint8){
    for (uint8 i; i < 4; i++){
        if(msg.sender == p[i]) return i;
    } return 7;
}


 function newGame() internal {
    newgame = 1;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "return" after wins[msg.sender] += 1; and move revert() after for

```
function claimWin() public {
    uint v = checkP();
    require (v != 7, "You are not a valid member of this game");

    uint8[4] memory dt =_players[msg.sender];

    for (uint8 e; e < 4; e++){
        if(dt[e] == 4){
            wins[msg.sender] += 1;
            return; // add it
        }
    } 
    revert();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked.